# Why can't I use forEach on this object?

Tags: javascript, foreach

this works

```
const itemsParent = document.querySelector('.items');
let items = [];

const renderItems = items => {

  items.forEach(item => {

    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'item';

    div.innerHTML = `
      <img class="itemImgBackground" src="assets/${item.name.replace(" ", "")}.png">
      <img class="itemImg" src="assets/${item.name.replace(" ", "")}.png">
      <span class="itemName"><a href="item.html?id=${item.id}">${item.name}</a></span>
      <span class="itemCondition">${item.condition}</span>
      <span class="itemPrice">${item.price}</span>
    `;

    itemsParent.appendChild(div);

  });
}

db.collection('items').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  console.log(typeof(querySnapshot));
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    docData = doc.data();
    docData['id'] = doc['id'];
    items.push(docData);
  });

  console.log(items);
  renderItems(items);

});
```

but this doesnt

```
const itemParent = document.querySelector('.item_full');
let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

var itemID = params.get('id');

var docRef = db.collection('items').doc(itemID);

docRef.get().then(doc => {
    doc.forEach(field => {
        console.log(field); 
    })
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

they're both objects, so it makes no sense.

Comment: `forEach` is a method from `array` no `object`

Comment: but they're BOTH objects....

Comment: Not all objects have the same properties.  `forEach` is specific to Array objects.

Comment: how do I check if something is an array object

Comment: `Array.isArray()`

Comment: `doc` is a single document, not an `array`, there you might want to use the `for of` loop.

Comment: `Array.isArray(yourObj)` // if `yourObj` is an array, returns `true` otherwise `false`.

Comment: `Array.isArray(querySnapshot)` returns false

Comment: Javascript also has "array-like" objects, which implement the methods necessary for iteration. `db.collection().get()` apparently returns one of these.

Comment: But `db.collection().doc(itemId)` just returns a single document, you don't need to use `.forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `.forEach()` on arrays and some array-like objects that implement Javascript's [iteration protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).

The object returned by `db.collection().get()` is a collection of documents, so it implements the iteration protocol.

The object returned by `db.collection().get().doc()` is just a single document. There's no need to iterate over a single item, so it doesn't implement this protocol. Just access the properties directly.

```
docRef.get().then(doc => {
    Object.keys(doc).forEach(field => console.log(field, doc[field]));
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```